# Will Q Learning algorithm produce the same result if I do not use e-greedy?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement Q-Learning algorithm but I do not have enough time to select the action by e-greedy.For simplicity I am choosing a random action,without any proper justification.Will this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, random action selection will allow `Q-learning` to learn an optimal policy. The goal of e-greedy exploration of to ensure that all the state-action pairs are (asymptotically) visited infinitely often, which is a convergence requirement [[Sutton & Barto, Section 6.5](http://incompleteideas.net/book/first/ebook/node65.html)]. Obviously, a random action selection process also complies this requirement.

The main drawback is that your agent will be acting poorly during all the learning stage. Also, maybe the convergence speed could be penalized, but I guess this last point is very application dependent.